# Django annotation and GROUP BY

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-orm

I am having trouble with making a query in django. Following is my model class:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date_time = models.DateField()
    total_assessment = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to:

```
SELECT event_type, SUM(total_assessment) as count 
from Registration
WHERE event_type in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
GROUP BY event_type
```

How can I translate this query to Django ORM.

I found this to be working for me:

```
Registration.objects.values('event_type').annotate(Sum('count')).filter(event_type__in=['VHRAssmntCompleted', 'VNAAssmntCompleted', 'PapSmear'])
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: no. This is the recommended way to doing group by query in django. You can find more about it here in official django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

Comment: You can always issue a `str(your_queryset.query)` in the shell (or have it printed/logged during execution) to check if the resulting SQL is in line with your expectations.

Comment: Also, [sqlparse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a godsend when analysing queries, so much so that it will be a Django dependency starting with v2.2.